# Create a line & label from centroid to edge of circle with Geometry Generator?

Tags: qgis

I'm looking to create a line from centroid of a circle and label it with the radius using the geometry generator but don't know where to start. QGIS 2.18.15.
I'm using the Ovals, Rectangles plugin to draw the circle.

Comment: Just FYI, I ran across this warning when searching for info on this plugin: "Be wary... That plugin has known issues and will cause your QGIS to get slower and slower over time." – ndawson

Comment: You can also create circles by buffering a point layer, if you want to avoid any issues this plugin may cause.

Answer (score 7):

#### Draw line from centroid to edge

Add a symbol layer to the polygon layer style.

Style the new symbol layer as Geometry Generator type (line), with this expression:

> make_line( centroid( $geometry), end_point( $geometry))

#### Label the line with the circle's radius

Label the layer with this expression:

> distance( centroid( $geometry), end_point( $geometry))

[image]

Adjust label placement to suit your preference. Show here with

- placement: offset from centroid
- quadrant: upper right

More labeling tips:

- use the round() function to reduce the number of decimal places

  > round(distance( centroid( $geometry), end_point( $geometry)),2)
- add units using the concatenate symbol ||

  > distance( centroid( $geometry), end_point( $geometry)) || ' meters'

[image]