# Create a line and label from centroid to edge of circle in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am looking to create a line from centroid of a circle and label it with the radius in ArcGis Pro (e.g. as per image below).

[image: image of what I wan to do]

I have to do it for a large number of circles so don't want to manually draw in polylines for each one, is there a way in ArcGIS Pro that can do it for the whole layer?

I see it is possible in QGIS:

[Create a line & label from centroid to edge of circle with Geometry Generator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282951/create-a-line-label-from-centroid-to-edge-of-circle-with-geometry-generator/451972#451972)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  A link to another Q&A is insufficient to do that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: If you have access to QGIS you may create the line layer in QGIS and display with label in ArcGIS PRO...